# og:image:secure_url not working in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I added og:image:secure_url metatag to my website.  When i ran it thru the facebook debugging tool, it finds the metatag but doesn't use the image.  Is it because i am using secure_url?  The image in the secure_url is a 1500px x 1500px png file, but facebook still isn't using it.  Facebook is using random images instead.
How do i get facebook to use the images that i specify in the metatag? https://www.phly.com/products/CyberSecurity.aspx

Here is what i found in the linter tool:

```
Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. og:image should be larger: Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'https://www.phly.com/CMSImages/Cyber_web31-915.png' will be used instead.
```

Raw Open Graph Document Information

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.phly.com/CMSImages/FB_Cyber31-4200.png" />
```

This what the scraper found:

```
"image": [
  {
     "url": "https://www.phly.com/products/../images/icons/bbbLogo.jpg",
     "secure_url": "https://www.phly.com/CMSImages/FB_Cyber31-4200.png",
     "width": 104,
     "height": 50
  },
  {
     "url": "https://www.phly.com/products/../images/logos/tokiomarinegroup.png"
  },
  {
     "url": "https://www.phly.com/products/../images/logos/PHLY_logoA1.png"
  },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Facebook debugger uses HTTP, that's why it doesn't try to find the secure image url (your page is not secure)

Comment: It is a random image because Facebook tries to find an image in your page.

Comment: I made a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Facebook debugger uses HTTP, that's why it doesn't try to find the secure image url (your page is not secure).

The image is (seems) random because Facebook tries to find an image in your page.

Comment: @user2658087: Does this fix your problem?